# Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 20.04 in PyEnv

Tags: python, pyenv, ubuntu-20.04

I have some legacy websites that run on Python 2.7.12 and have just updated my dev machine to Ubuntu 20.04.

I am trying to get PyEnv to install Python 2.7.12, but it seems that this depends on libssl1.0-dev which has been dropped in Ubuntu 20.04.

I get error:

```
Installing Python-2.7.12...
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?

Please consult to the Wiki page to fix the problem.
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems


BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using python-build 20180424)
```

Following advice [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems) I run:

```
sudo apt-get remove libssl-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
```

I get error:

`E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate`

Is there any way of doing this?  If so then how please?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered to run your legacy application in a Docker container? That way you don't need to clutter the whole system with old dependecies.

Comment: Thanks.  I've never used Docker before, but am up for trying.  That said, it looks like the oldest supported version of Python is 2.7.17 https://gitlab.com/python-devs/ci-images  Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: You're looking on worong side. https://hub.docker.com/_/python is the official docker hub for python images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Klaus mentioned you could use docker image for p[ython 2.7](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&name=2.7), but ssl library is very crucial, so it's weird that it has no installation candidate. The package `libssl-dev` for focal is listed [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libssl-dev)

Comment: I believe it was depreciated in favour of libssl1.1-dev.  I've decided to roll back to a previous OS though as by brain was starting to bleed with this.  Thanks for the link though, I may still try it because I am now having other problems having rolled back to Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Comment: I've just had a play with docker and it seems to be amazing.  It looks like this will solve it for me, so thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can install libssl1.0-dev from previous **Ubuntu 18.04** release:

```
wget -P /tmp/ http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.5_amd64.deb
wget -P /tmp/ http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.5_amd64.deb
apt install /tmp/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.5_amd64.deb
apt install /tmp/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.5_amd64.deb
```

It works, butthis is not recommend way. Because libssl1.0 package will not receive security updates in the future! Maybe python 2.7.17 is OK for you? You can install it via apt:

```
apt install python2
```

Comment: The 2 links in the answer are no longer valid. The updated commands for `wget` would be:
`wget -P /tmp/ http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb` and
`wget -P /tmp/ http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb`. The updated commands for `apt install` would be: `sudo apt install /tmp/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb` and `sudo apt install /tmp/libssl1.0-dev_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see a way of getting PyEnv to work with such an old version of Python, so opted for using Docker as suggested by Klaus and Rafal.  Thank you.

For others struggling with this, [here is a handy overview of the process](https://realpython.com/python-versions-docker/).